# detecting a string charset

Tags: c++, linux, character-encoding

i am looking for the best linux library that will let me detect a string charset. 
any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ICU is a quite good library, you might use [ucsdet_detect](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/ucsdet_8h.html#9f3eb31ff3d5194f9ac915214a8e94fd) or ucsdet_detectAll to detect 'possible' matches on the charset of an input buffer.